# Excel function and expression for counting only certain items included on an invoice

Tags: excel, selection, criteria

I would like to count the number of "Invoices" that had a sale of a certain item (lets say "ABC" i don't want to count the invoice if it didn't have a "ABC" on the sale so in the example below, invoice 3 would not be counted because a "ABC" was not included on that invoice); then if it did have an "ABC" on the invoice, i want to count variations of size and color (for example i may want to count number of color yellow or size 12's; or number of invoices that had size 11 and 21 on the invoice)

Could someone help me with the function to use in excel? and the expression? I'm thinking countifs? but i'm new to excel, thanks!

```
customer      date    invoice item    size    color
-------------.-------.-------.-------.-------.---------
me            1012014       1 abc          23 brown    
you           1012014       2 abc          11 black    
you           1012014       2 bqr          14 red    
you           1012014       2 rpg          12 red    
someoneelse   1022014       3 erp          12 yellow    
someoneelse   1022014       3 rky          21 blue    
them          1102014       4 abc          14 red
```

Comment: Will each individual item only appear once on each invoice? (if it does appear?)

Comment: Have you tried a Pivot table with `item` as row labels and filters?

Comment: its more than just 'ABC'; there are actually about 20 or 30 items, that if they match any of those items, then it should be counted on the report if the other criteria are met... so it might be if item=(abc,or dse, or jeg, or uer, or wer, or uio, etc)

Comment: I'm pretty good with pivot tables, but don't think thats realistic; unless i'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming numeric invoices in `C2:C10` and items in `D2:D10` this "array formula" will give the result 3 (different numbered invoices which include item "abc")

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D10="abc",C2:C10),C2:C10),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

For an `"OR"` as per your comment you can use + like this

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((D2:D10="abc")+(D2:D10="cde")+(D2:D10="fff"),C2:C10),C2:C10),1))`

or use `MATCH` like this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2:D10,{"abc","cde","fff"},0)),C2:C10),C2:C10),1))`

which can be more easily extended for 30 items - you can list them all out in the formula or if they are recorded somewhere on the spreadsheet, like `G1:G30` then you can use that range in the formula, i.e.

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2:D10,G1:G30,0)),C2:C10),C2:C10),1))`

Comment: no, i can't guarantee that it only occurs once per instance; actually there are about 30 items that if the invoice has one of those 30 items, then it can be used for counting on the report.

Comment: so if i have more than just ABC as criteria, would this be correct?  =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D10=("abc" or "cde" or "fff"),C2:C10),C2:C10),1))

Comment: I updated my answer to give some options for matching multiple items

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a Pivot Table is what you require:

[image]

This should answer all the example questions you asked, but with a pivot table, you have the ability to drag and drop columns around QUICKLY to answer other questions, without writing possibly complex formulas.

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIF seems to be exactly what you need. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx